# Implementing a cell-based widget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to implement a cell-based widget similar to the one in [Jupyter Notebook](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/images/jupyter/example-notebook.png) in Qt where multiple cells are stacked vertically. Each cell is made of a `QTextEdit` and multiple buttons and the cell's vertical size would grow by entering more text into the text edit (i.e. no vertical scrollbars in the text edit).

However I'm not sure what the best way would be to implement such a widget in Qt. I've tried a `QListWidget` with a custom widget (made of a `QTextEdit` and a couple of buttons) for each item, however the custom widget wouldn't grow vertically by entering more text and instead the `QTextEdit` scrollbars would show up. I also implemented a second version using `QListView` and `QStyledItemDelegate` however I encountered multiple issues including not being able to interact with the painted buttons (through the delegate).

Any suggestions/examples about how to implement such a cell-based widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `QTextEdit` and listen for changes in the **document** size using `document()->size()` (not the size of the QTextEdit, mind). You can then resize the `QTextEdit`'s parent to reflect the new size. To fill the parent with the widget, use a layout. I've used `QVBoxLayout` several times below for this purpose. (One, to hold multiple `QTextEdit` widgets in a vertical column; Two, to hold a single TextEdit).

```cpp
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtWidgets>

class DyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DyTextEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QTextEdit(parent)
    {
        QTextDocument *doc = document();
        currentSize = doc->size();

        qDebug() << "[Init] Size:" << currentSize;

        //  listen to text/content changes
        connect(this, &QTextEdit::textChanged, this, &DyTextEdit::on_textChanged);

        //  connect <> 
        connect(this, &DyTextEdit::sizeChanged, this, &DyTextEdit::resizeParent);

        doc->setTextWidth(-1);

        emit sizeChanged(currentSize);  //  init
    }

signals:
    //  emitted when document size changes
    void sizeChanged(QSizeF size);

public slots:
    void on_textChanged()
    {
        QSizeF newSize = document()->size();

        qDebug() << "[TextChanged] Size:" << newSize;

        //  detect changes in the document size
        if (newSize != currentSize)
            emit sizeChanged(newSize);  //  emit signal

        //  update size
        currentSize = newSize;
    }

    void resizeParent(QSizeF size)
    {
        //  resize the parent's height, don't bother with the width
        parentWidget()->setFixedHeight(size.height());
    }

private:
    QSizeF currentSize; //  keeps track of current document size

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //  holds all dytextedits
    QWidget aggregateWidget;
    QVBoxLayout aggregateLayout(&aggregateWidget);

    //  note: for scalability, use a QList (or QLists)

    //  first textbox
    QWidget widget;
    QVBoxLayout vbLayout(&widget);
    vbLayout.setMargin(0);
    DyTextEdit dytext(&widget);
    vbLayout.addWidget(&dytext);

    //  first button row
    QHBoxLayout hbLayout(&widget);
    hbLayout.setMargin(0);
    QPushButton pb1a("Push this.", &widget);
    hbLayout.addWidget(&pb1a);
    QPushButton pb1b("Push this.", &widget);
    hbLayout.addWidget(&pb1b);

    //  second textbox
    QWidget widget2;
    QVBoxLayout vbLayout2(&widget2);
    vbLayout2.setMargin(0);
    DyTextEdit dytext2(&widget2);
    vbLayout2.addWidget(&dytext2);

    //  second button row
    QHBoxLayout hbLayout2(&widget2);
    hbLayout2.setMargin(0);
    QPushButton pb2a("Push this.", &widget2);
    hbLayout2.addWidget(&pb2a);
    QPushButton pb2b("Push this.", &widget2);
    hbLayout2.addWidget(&pb2b);

    //  add widgets to layout
    aggregateLayout.addWidget(&widget);     //  cell 1
    aggregateLayout.addLayout(&hbLayout);   //  |
    aggregateLayout.addWidget(&widget2);    //  cell 2
    aggregateLayout.addLayout(&hbLayout2);  //  |

    aggregateLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize);

    aggregateWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc" //  include if there are QObject classes in main.cpp
```

Note that above, I've used rows of buttons using `QHBoxLayout` and added them to the overall, aggregate layout detached from the textbox widgets. You can still use a say, `QGridLayout` if you wish to set your buttons in a different format. You can also combine the textedits and button layouts as children under another widget (to serve as an umbrella) covering both. That would more clearly form a **cell** of widget and may be easier to move around. (I've uploaded a workable example of this on [Github](https://github.com/TrebledJ/stackoverflow/tree/master/53800168).)

#### Demo (macOS):

This is a screenshot of after typing content and copy-pasting content.

[image: demonstration using both typed and copied content]

Note that the aggregate widget will contract on removal of lines of text.

Comment: Great, thanks! Btw if the text in the `DyTextEdit` is too long, the `Cell` widget goes off the viewport. I guess I have to subclass the `CellBased` widget from `QScrollArea` to be able to scroll through the cells? Or subclassing `QListView` and possibly non-uniform cell height is a better option?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking you could contain the widget in say, another widget with a scrollarea, your main GUI interface or a MainWindow perhaps. Then you can scroll through the cells that way?

Comment: I see. I think a scrollarea in the MainWindow could be a good option. I'll give it a shot.